# Had a skin biopsy of a suspicious mole (10 stitches) -- how to prevent ugly scar-tissue from forming? Make scar less noticeable?

Tags: stitches, biopsy, scar-tissue-scars, moles, melanoma

Recently, I had a suspicious mole removed (skin biopsy) to be tested for melanoma (I've had a few of this nature), but this one was quite deep and large, and required 10 stitches. **How to prevent a big nasty scar from forming?** **Are their treatments/medications specifically designed for scar-tissue prevention?**